# C# index list of objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, indexing

How do I use an index in C# in order to keep track of a list of questions?

The list has five questions, so that when the first one is loaded on the quiz page, the user provides an answer with the click of a button, which then goes to the answer page, which tells the user if they were right or wrong. On the answer page the user will click a "next question" button, which should load the next question in the list back on the quiz page. This should some how keep the index , so that the code knows that the second question is now to be loaded.

This gets the full list of questions:

```
public static IEnumerable<QuizGroups> GetGroups(string sectorId)
{                
    var Quizes = _QuizDataSource.AllQuizGroups.Where(x => x.Subtitle == sectorId);
    return Quizes;    
}
```

How do I use an index to iterate through the list of questions? There are 5 questions in the list.

Comment: what do you mean by `keep track of a list of questions`? your code seems to be OK unless it's not what you want.

Comment: This doesn't return a _list_.

Comment: Your GetGroup() method shouls return IList<QuizGroups> type

Comment: The Quizes *should* already have an identifier - either a unique ID or a unique composite ID with the "container" for a given quiz. Using this *existing identifier* will ensure consistency in finding the *same quiz* across multiple data contexts and *fail fast* (as opposed to work with incorrect results) behavior.

Comment: please see the edited question for a better explanation

Comment: Also, make sure that an ordering for the enumerable is established. (Or the quizzes may appear in an unpredictable order, which could really make indexing .. extra fun.)

Answer (score 2):

> There are 5 questions in the list.

You don't return a `List<QuizGroups>` but an `IEnumerable<QuizGroups>`. That's probably an "unmaterialized" query and not a collection. Otherwise you could use it's indexer directly to acces an item.

If there are only 5 items returned you could use `ToList` to create a real list. If you only need 5 and you want to ensure that, you can use `Take(5)` before:

```
public static IList<QuizGroups> GetGroups(string sectorId) 
{
    var Quizes = _QuizDataSource.AllQuizGroups
        .Where(x => x.Subtitle == sectorId)
        .OrderBy(x => CreatedAt)
        .Take(5)
        .ToList();
    return Quizes;
}
```

Now you can use the indexer or `Enumerable.ElementAt`:

```
IList<QuizGroups> groups = GetGroups(sectorID);
QuizGroups quiz1 = groups[0]; // via indexer
QuizGroups quiz2 = groups.ElementAt(1); // via ElementAt, can throw an exception if there are less than 2
QuizGroups quiz3 = groups.ElementAt(2); // via ElementAtOrDefault, null if there are less than 3
// ...
```

Note that you don't need to use `ToList` in `GetGroups` to create a collection first. You could use `ElementAt` directly, but then you would always execute the query when you access the next index.

**Edit** according to your new background informations: I assume that you need to order the list by a `DateTime` property to ensure the correct order. Therefore i've added `OrderBy` in the query in `GetGroups`.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list from the Quizes with

```
var quizesList = Quizez.ToList();
```

and then:

```
for(int index = 0; index < quizesList.Count(); index++)
{
     //Access Item at Index with quizesList[index];
}
```

---

or you can use [ElementAt(int index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  for(int index = 0; index < Quizes.Count(); index++)
    {
         //Access Item at Index with Quizes.ElementAt(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the index for anything else in your code.
If not, I would use a `foreach`

```
foreach(var quizGroup in GetGroups(1))
{
   //you now have a reference to each quiz group as you're going through the list
}
```

Or for individual access

```
var q = GetGroups(1).ToList();
q[0]
q[1]
...
q[q.Count - 1]
```